# Make a 2D array in a struct, store strings inside array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to make a library system using structs and pointers, that registers a person with their name, ID, phone number, and the name of the books (maximum 3). I have created a struct for every borrower, and I am trying to store input taken by the user, specifically at the part of getting the book titles, to store into an array of other structs (for other borrowers). I have to be able to free the locations of the borrowers once they return all books, so I'd have to use dynamic memory for that.

This is the code I have so far, not sure how exactly I would go about storing every borrower using pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define MAX_NAME_SZ 256
#define CLEAR() system("CLS")

struct borrower
{
    char name[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char id[7];
    char phoneNumber[10];
    char titleOfBook[3][20];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct borrower b;
    char op;

    do
    {
        puts("\n1) Register borrower");
        puts("2) Find by ID");
        puts("3) Show All");
        puts("4) Erase by ID");
        puts("0) Exit");
        printf("Option:");

        setbuf(stdin, 0);
        opc=getchar();

        switch(op)
        {
            case '1':
                RegisterBorrower(&b);
                break;

            case '2':
                //showID();
                break;

            case '3':
                //showAll();
                break;

            case '4':
                //erase();
                break;

            case '0':
                break;
        }
        }while (op!=48);

    return 0;

}

void RegisterBorrower(struct borrower *b)
{
    CLEAR();
    setbuf(stdin,0);
    printf("ID: "); gets(p->id);
    printf("Name: "); gets(p->name);
    printf("Last Name: "); gets(p->lastName);
    setbuf(stdin,0);
    printf("Phone Number: "); gets(p->phoneNumber);

    int numberOfBooks=0, cont=0, i;
    char bookTitle[20];
    printf("How many books do you want to take out?(max 3): ");
    scanf("%d", &numberOfBooks);
    setbuf(stdin,0);
    if(numberOfBooks<=3 && numberOfBooks>0)
    {
        for(i=0; i<numberOfBooks; i++)
        {
            setbuf(stdin,0);
            printf("Book Title: "); gets(bookTitle);
            strcpy(p->titleOfBook[i][0], bookTitle);
        }
    }else
    {
        printf("You cannot take out this amount of books.");
    }
}
```

Everything "works" (doesn't crash) up until the part I ask for the book titles, it only runs once. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
My problem was that I used

```
strcpy(p->titleOfBook[i][0], bookTitle);
```

which only copies to one character because of the [0]. I changed it to

```
strcpy(p->titleOfBook[i], bookTitle);
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Note: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359)

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response, I read your comment and noticed the error you pointed out, and changed it in my question. I was translating from another language and got the variables mixed up. Got busy and didn't have time to reply right away as I didnt think you'd be refreshing this post so quickly haha. I changed the code to ```p->titleOfBook[i]```, and was able to not crash. Thank you

Comment: @Fe2O3 You wrote: "the SO practice of not changing questions so as to invalidate comments" There is no such "SO practice". It is perfectly fine to do changes that invalidates **comments**. The "SO practice" is only for answers.

Comment: @SupportUkraine The SO SOP changes to suit the whims of whomever is reading/typing.

Comment: @mexicanburrito Post example input used - including the longest for each `struct` member.

Comment: @Fe2O3 While it's true that many SO SOPs ain't set in stone there is no doubt about that "edits invalidating comments" are fine. Actually many comments ask for actions that will automatically invalidate the comment itself, e.g. "Post your code", "Indent your code", "Post example input used" (see just above).... If you want to post something that "stays valid", post an answer - not a comment.

Comment: "I have to be able to free the locations of the borrowers once they return all books, so I'd have to use dynamic memory for that." So why aren't you doing that, if it's a requirement?

Comment: @Lundin I haven't posted that because I don't know how to do that yet.